# How to access USGS national map viewer?

Tags: openlayers-2

I know that I can use arcGIS to display the USGS national map viewer (aerial, raster, topographical, etc), but I will be using API for commercial use and it would cost $4,000.

1) Can I use openlayers to display the USGS national map?  If so, please provide a link.

2) Does USGS have an API?  If so, please provide a link.

3) If there are no free methods of displaying the USGS national map, what is the cheapest method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest free way would be to use OpenLayers which is a openSource web mapping API and add the USGS national map to it as a WMS layer.

[OpenLayers Link](http://openlayers.org/)

[USGS WMS Layer Link](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/Combined)

## UPDATE per demo request:

Well that took me longer than expected. It's strange that usgs doesn't have these services cached, they would be a lot faster. Anyway...
[image]

**[HERE's the DEMO](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/arcgis.htm)**

More on how to give me credit [HERE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me how to add the USGS national map as a layer as a WMS layer to openlayers?  Possibly a link?

Comment: Sure, i'll create the page and post a link.

Comment: The USGS WMS layer link comes from arcGIS and I'm trying not to use arcGIS because I am trying to start a commercial venture.  To use the arcGIS API, it would cost $4k.  Thanks.

Comment: The link is to an ArcGIS server USGS has already payed for. They are providing it as a service for free. It does not cost anyone anything to use this service. USGS bought the license to ArcGIS Server and are using ArcGIS server to publish these maps. You will be using the free OpenLayers API to display that mapservice on your website. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "usgs doesn't have these services cached"? Do you mean the pngs are generated upon request rather than simply being served up?

Comment: @Corey Yes, I'm not an ArcGIS pro or anything. But notice how in [their service metadata](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/Combined/SDDS_Imagery/MapServer) the `Single Fused Map Cache: false` and there is no tile set definition. So i believe it is NOT cached.